# how to manage sum in a loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm new to the pyhton world so your help is essential.
I have a problem with data handling and operation in for loops in pandas.
In short, after some data manipulation, I have a dataframe of 3 columns and a variable number of rows, could be 10 as well as 2000000. the three columns are Date, % change and Week days. Ticker_Ch frame here below.

```
          Date  % Change  Week days
0   2021-01-04       NaN     Monday
1   2021-01-05      0.69    Tuesday
2   2021-01-06      0.60  Wednesday
3   2021-01-07      1.49   Thursday
4   2021-01-08      0.57     Friday
..         ...       ...        ...
574 2023-04-17      0.36     Monday
575 2023-04-18      0.07    Tuesday
576 2023-04-19     -0.02  Wednesday
577 2023-04-20     -0.55   Thursday
578 2023-04-21      0.08     Friday
```

I need to create a list by adding the rows of the %change column for each month. the result of the sum should be stored in a list where in position 0 I have the sum of the column %change for the month January, then 0..in position 1 February and so on.

I can generate the sum without looping, for a specific month using the code below:

```py
month=("10")
df2 = Ticker_Ch[Ticker_Ch['Date'].dt.strftime('%m') == month] 
print(df2)
print(df2['% Change'].sum())
```

but when I put it all into a loop I have problem.

```py
month=("10")
cum_month=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
for x in range(len(month)):
    df2 = Ticker_Ch[Ticker_Ch['Date'].dt.strftime('%m') == month] 
    print (x)
    print(df2['% Change'].sum())
    cum_month[x]= df2['% Change'].sum()
    print(cum_month)
```

the result here below, seems made two times the cycle

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
0
14.989999999999998
[14.989999999999998, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
1
14.989999999999998
[14.989999999999998, 14.989999999999998, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

whereas while when I want to search for two months, the result always comes out equal to 0

```py
month=("10","11")
cum_month=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
for x in range(len(month)):
    df2 = Ticker_Ch[Ticker_Ch['Date'].dt.strftime('%m') == month] 
    print (x)
    print(df2['% Change'].sum())
    cum_month[x]= df2['% Change'].sum()
    print(cum_month)
```

here the results

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
0
0.0
[0.0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
1
0.0
[0.0, 0.0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Can someones help me in order to understand Why I'm wrong?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your results in a different list, not in the one you're iterating over:

```
result = []
for m in range(1, 13):
    df2 = Ticker_Ch[Ticker_Ch['Date'].dt.strftime('%m') == str(m).zfill(2)] 
    result.append(df2['% Change'].sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
df2 = Ticker_Ch[Ticker_Ch['Date'].dt.strftime('%m') == month]
```

you are comparing with `month`, when you should be comparing with `month[x]`.

Having said that, it should be possible to do this without explicit loops, using something like (untested!)

```
Ticker_Ch.groupby(Ticker_Ch['date'].dt.month).sum()
```